# Conditionally apply one of two classes in Angular, after input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular, and would like to apply a class conditionally.

I would like to evaluate user input for a drug dose, and add a `.green` class to the output if it is below a set cutoff, and `.red` class if it is above the cutoff.

**Before the drug dose has been entered, I would like to apply neither class** - and that is the root of my problem.

I know how to apply the classes conditionally with `ng-class` once the dose has been entered:

```
// Template
<input type="number" ng-model="dose" ng-change="checkDose()" /> ...
<div ng-class="$doseIsAcceptable ? 'green' : 'red'">{{ dose }}</div>
// Controller
$scope.checkDose = function() { 
  $scope.doseIsAcceptable = ($scope.dose < 10.0) ? true : false;
};
```

However, what I'm not sure how to do is **not apply any class (either green or red) until the dose has been entered**.

At the moment the red class is being applied initially, I guess because `$doseIsAcceptable` is initially undefined and therefore evaluates as false.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
<div ng-class="{'true':'green', 'false':'red'}[doseIsAcceptable]">{{ dose }}</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nKDKs/

Comment: a very elegant solution!!

Comment: @arturgrzesiak thank you , it is because the Angular is very elegant framework :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Richard

```
<div ng-class="doseIsAcceptable">{{ dose }}</div>
```

This will work by binding class name (without dots), like:

```
$scope.doseIsAcceptable = '';
$scope.doseIsAcceptable = 'red';
$scope.doseIsAcceptable = 'green';
```

Peter

Comment: And what if some other functions in controller uses the `doseIsAcceptable` as `Boolean` and not as `String`?

Comment: What if ... I've just posted another solution. I guess another SO topic will be started to answer above "what if"